# Exit flag in pyOptSparseDriver

Tags: openmdao

I need the ability to specify an exit flag if something failed. The OpenMDAO documentation for the [pyoptsparse_driver](http://openmdao-kgm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/srcdocs/packages/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.html) has the option for an exit flag. However, when I run it with an exit flag as an option it says that `Option 'exit_flag' has not been added`. Also I am also not sure how to actually specify if something failed or not. Would I need to pass the flag out of the component that failed in the solve_nonlinear() and somehow use that to set the option on the pyoptsparse_driver? I want to do something kind of like this but I'm not sure on the syntax and I can't find an example:

```
def solve_nonlinear(self, params, unknowns, resids):
    unknowns['y'], exit_flag = function(params['x'])
    self.exit_flag = exit_flag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of issues here:

**1)** "How do I propagate failure information from a component up to the optimizer?"
We don't currently have a way of handling this. Its something we'll be working on in the near future though

**2)** If a component does fail, what is the proper response? 
Depends on what you're doing. For a DOE, you should probably just log the failed case and keep going. For a gradient free method, probably some kind of objective penalization is warranted. For a gradient based algorithm, you likely need to back-track on the line-search (or use some other similar kind of walk back mechanism).

**3)** In the event that it all fails, can the driver report an overall exit status out. 
Again, we don't have this implemented yet in a general way. The option you found in pyopt_sparse driver is a mistake in the doc-string. There is an [exit_flag attribute that gets set based on the internal pyopt state though.](https://github.com/OpenMDAO/OpenMDAO/blob/master/openmdao/drivers/pyoptsparse_driver.py#L303)